# Cassandra: Python equivalent method to `sstabledump`?

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm writing an application to read cassandra sstable files (e.g. mc-1-big-Data.db).we don't want to do it with "sstabledump" command which will require us to install cassandra in our cluster. So do we have a python utility which can read .db files and give me a output in json format.

Answer (score 0):

There's no equivalent to sstabledump in Python Im aware of that would allow to access C* sstables directly.

Some solutions are to leverage either cqlsh COPY TO (csv or txt format) or dsbulk to get the data in json format directly

https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/cqlsh.html#copy-to

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/cql/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh_commands/cqlshCopy.html

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkCmd.html

Note that the latter (dsbulk) will leverage the java driver and connect via the client port to pull the information from the cluster, putting some strain on the cluster during the extraction - same problem with CQLSH though.

As to using sstabledump, reading the sstables directly is not necessarily a recommendable approach as it would include tombstones and duplicates based on the Replication Factor so having the engine to parse the data is in most situations a better option (but if really the goal is to do that, then installing C* on the app cluster in question might be the only way).

EDIT:
So sstable2json was deprecated as per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7464 as I see it's part of the repo mentioned in the response provided and the jira explains the reasoning behind it.

I havent tested the solution in the repo, but dsbulk has one advantage over `COPY TO` which is that it does multi-thread as it leverages the java driver. And can be used for querying or dumping a table - see example below exporting table `ks.kv`.

```
$ dsbulk unload -h $(hostname -i) -k ks -t kv --connector.name json --connector.json.url /home/user/export
Operation directory: /home/automaton/logs/UNLOAD_20200114-092515-429006
total | failed | rows/s | p50ms | p99ms | p999ms
    9 |      0 |     30 |  2.94 |  7.50 |   7.50
Operation UNLOAD_20200114-092515-429006 completed successfully in 0 seconds.
```

```
$ head /home/user/export/output-000001.json 
{"k":5,"v":5}
{"k":1,"v":1}
...
```

Im afraid there's no out of the box solution (Im aware of) for python equivalent of sstable2json on more recent versions

Comment: Thanks for your reply. copy to command is very slow to download bulk data. duplicate data we can manage it.I have got some piece of code here https://github.com/bharatendra/ctools . but it seems it is not working as is it may require some modification.

Comment: Edited the response above to expand it. Hope it helps. As to your repository, I take it depends on the C* version used and sstables version (as dsbulk will only work from C* 2.1 but previous versions should be OK with the tools you mention such as sstable2json). Sorry if it doesnt fit your request

Comment: Okay i will test the performance for this utility.So it is comparable with spark performance?

Comment: I wouldnt go as far as that. Spark spreads over multiple systems and split the load in a way that dsbulk cannot. It's better than COPY, but it's not a replacement for Spark